# Retuning Data From SQL Server database into Class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to fill a class with data from a SQL Server table.

I've done the exact thing before using Java for another application (see below)

```
public LanguageList getSystemLanguages() throws SQLException 
{
    String sql;
    LanguageList language;
    sql = "Select DISTINCT code_language From CODE";
    prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rset = prest.executeQuery();
    language = new LanguageList(rset);
    return language;
}
```

In C# I have so far:

```
public Incident GetIncidentViaLogID(String LogID)
{
     Incident incident;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Incident WHERE LogID = @LogID";
     cmd.Connection = conn;
     SqlParameter p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@LogID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     p1.Value = LogID;
     p1.Size = -1;
     cmd.Prepare();

     //Load data into class
}
```

I've tried numerous things to finish off this method but none have worked. What would be the approach to complete this method?

Thanks!

Comment: In which way do I execute it and return it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean: how do I load this into a class. There are several options for that, but the most used solution is [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that may help you.

let your class is

```
          class Person
                {
                   public int age;
                   public string name;
                }
```

Create an object

```
                Person p1 = null; 

                List<Person> personList = new List<Person>(); //To fill with data retrieve from database 
//Method to fill Class with data


               public void getAllPersonData()
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                        }

                        string query = "SELECT * FROM Persons";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            p1 = new Person(); //Create Instances
                            p1.age = rdr.GetInt32(0);
                            p1.name = rdr.GetString(1);
                            personList.Add(p1);                                
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException x)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                    }
                }
```